# how to efficiently count events on mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out how to do this in the most efficient way given that I have large tables.

I have two tables: `photos` and `favorites` (think something like Flickr or Facebook :-).

For each photo P, I want a count of the  total number of favorites the creator of P received on her photos before she uploaded P. In other words, I want a count of the favorites submitted up until the moment she shared P.

The table `photos` includes the columns: `id`, `user_id`, `upload_timestamp`.

The table `favorites` includes the columns: `photo_id`, `user_id` (the user favoriting), `fave_timestamp`.

The result set should have the columns: `photo_id, user_id (creator of the photo), pre_faves_count`.

The `photos` table has 2 million records. The `favorites` has 10 million records.

I have tried doing something like

```
select count(favorites) 
FROM favorites, photos 
WHERE favorites.photo_id 
  and photos.id 
  and favorites.fave_timestamp < photos.upload_timestamp 
group by favorites.photo_id, favorites.user_id
```

-- but i am pretty sure it's not correct

Comment: I have indices on the id's of each table.

Comment: I have tried doing something like select count(favorites) FROM `favorites`, `photos`  WHERE favorites.photo_id and photos.id and favorites.fave_timestamp < photos.upload_timestamp group by  favorites.photo_id,  favorites.user_id -- but i am pretty sure it's not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be real slow. Don't even try it on your 2M and 10M tables, without adding indexes first:

```
SELECT 
      p.id               AS photo_id
    , p.user_id          AS user_id
    , COUNT(f.photo_id)  AS pre_faves_count
FROM 
      photos AS p
  JOIN
      photos AS allp
          ON allp.user_id = p.user_id
  LEFT JOIN
      favorites AS f
          ON  f.photo_id = allp.id 
          AND f.fave_timestamp < p.upload_timestamp 
GROUP BY 
      p.id 
    , p.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I figured out a slightly faster way of doing it: select photos.id, photos.user_id, (select count(*) from favorites where favorites.user_id = photos.user_id and favorites.fav_timestamp < photos.upload_timestamp) from photos;

Comment: @andersmh: Do you want to count the votes one has received (my query) or the votes one has given (your query, one Join less needed)?